# Delete random records in a dataset matching specific criteria based in variables in another table in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset called `survey_data` following this structure:

```
 dput(survey_data)
structure(list(id = structure(1:20, levels = c("118471098691", 
"118471042050", "118471014713", "118470994901", "118470283421", 
"118470281485", "118470282930", "118470269057", "118470266821", 
"118470265552", "118470171081", "118470141169", "118470145488", 
"118470049005", "118470032085", "118470026348", "118470006683", 
"118470014124", "118470001292", "118469994597"), class = "factor"), 
    gender = c("Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
    "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", 
    "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
    "Female"), age = c("Aged 18-24", "Aged 25-32", "Aged 16-17", 
    "Aged 16-17", "Aged 18-24", "Aged 16-17", "Aged 16-17", "Aged 16-17", 
    "Aged 18-24", "Aged 16-17", "Aged 16-17", "Aged 18-24", "Aged 16-17", 
    "Aged 18-24", "Aged 16-17", "Aged 16-17", "Aged 25-32", "Aged 16-17", 
    "Aged 16-17", "Aged 16-17"), location = c("North West", "Northern Ireland", 
    "North East", "North West", "London", "London", "South East", 
    "West Midlands", "London", "South West", "North East", "North East", 
    "South West", "London", "West Midlands", "Wales", "Northern Ireland", 
    "South East", "East Midlands", "West Midlands"), occupation = c("Student", 
    "Employed full time", "Student", "Student", "Employed full time", 
    "Student", "Student", "Student", "Student", "Student", "Student", 
    "Student", "Unemployed", "Employed part time", "Student", 
    "Student", "Employed full time", "Student", "Student", "Student"
    ), income = c("Under £10,000", "£75,001 - £100,000", "Under £10,000", 
    "Under £10,000", "£25,001 - £50,000", "Under £10,000", 
    "Under £10,000", "Under £10,000", "£75,001 - £100,000", 
    "Under £10,000", "Under £10,000", "£10,001 - £25,000", 
    "Under £10,000", "Under £10,000", "Under £10,000", "Under £10,000", 
    "£25,001 - £50,000", "£10,001 - £25,000", "£10,001 - £25,000", 
    "£10,001 - £25,000")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(id = structure(list(levels = NULL, ordered = FALSE, 
        include_na = FALSE), class = c("collector_factor", "collector"
    )), gender = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), age = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), location = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), occupation = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), income = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x6000001b8070>, class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This dataset is a result from an online survey and it contains near 10,000 observations and more than 150 variables.

In order to correct some oversampling and make the respondent profile match the population profile I would need to reject some of these records at random. To do so, I have another two tables, one for males and another for females with the number of records to delete in every combination of age and gender, like:

`males_reject`:

```
 dput(males_reject)
structure(list(region = c("North East", "North West", "Yorkshire and the Humber", 
"East Midlands", "West Midlands", "East of England", "London", 
"South East", "South West", "Northern Ireland", "Scotland", "Wales"
), `Aged 16-17` = c(0, 8, 1, 1, 4, 0, 7, 2, 4, 0, 2, 1), `Aged 18-24` = c(20, 
28, 17, 9, 32, 8, 74, 26, 10, 0, 0, 14), `Aged 25-32` = c(0, 
2, 0, 0, 9, 0, 7, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0), `Aged 33-40` = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 
8, 4, 3, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1), `Aged 41-50` = c(2, 5, 3, 2, 4, 4, 2, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1), `Aged 51-56` = c(0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0), `Aged 57-67` = c(4, 12, 6, 2, 2, 1, 0, 6, 6, 1, 6, 1), 
    `Aged 68-76` = c(3, 6, 7, 4, 0, 0, 6, 2, 4, 3, 5, 0), `Aged 76+` = c(1, 
    3, 7, 0, 4, 0, 0, 5, 3, 0, 4, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -12L
), spec = structure(list(cols = list(region = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), `Aged 16-17` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `Aged 18-24` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `Aged 25-32` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `Aged 33-40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `Aged 41-50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `Aged 51-56` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `Aged 57-67` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `Aged 68-76` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `Aged 76+` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x6000001a8590>, class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and another similar for the females group:

```
dput(females_reject)
structure(list(region = c("North East", "North West", "Yorkshire and The Humber", 
"East Midlands", "West Midlands", "East", "London", "South East", 
"South West", "Northern Ireland", "Scotland", "Wales"), `Aged 16-17` = c(5, 
16, 14, 13, 19, 13, 37, 11, 13, 2, 6, 9), `Aged 18-24` = c(0, 
4, 0, 3, 11, 0, 21, 5, 3, 3, 0, 0), `Aged 25-32` = c(2, 8, 11, 
13, 7, 11, 2, 16, 3, 0, 6, 4), `Aged 33-40` = c(9, 15, 17, 11, 
13, 10, 5, 15, 17, 6, 10, 7), `Aged 41-50` = c(7, 0, 3, 2, 12, 
9, 6, 0, 11, 0, 0, 11), `Aged 51-56` = c(2, 6, 1, 0, 6, 5, 0, 
7, 0, 0, 5, 4), `Aged 57-67` = c(3, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18, 3, 
0, 3, 8), `Aged 68-76` = c(0, 6, 5, 3, 2, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 3, 1
), `Aged 76+` = c(2, 4, 5, 6, 1, 8, 3, 11, 4, 0, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(region = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), `Aged 16-17` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `Aged 18-24` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `Aged 25-32` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `Aged 33-40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `Aged 41-50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `Aged 51-56` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `Aged 57-67` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `Aged 68-76` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `Aged 76+` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x6000001ac390>, class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Provided the size of the dataset I need a way to automate this and write a code that takes the `males_reject` and `females_reject` tables and use these numbers to reject at random as many observations in the `survey_data` table that matcht the age/gender definition.

Therefore, the expected result is a dataset as the original `survey_data` one but with 20 records deleted (randomly selected) being males 18-24 years old in the North East, 28 records deleted being males 18-24 years old in the North West and so on (following the tables above).

But I don't know even how to start approaching the problem, since the `males_reject` and `females_reject` tables are not *data suitable to be joined*, but information to use in the script to define filters and decide how many records have to be deleted.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** The values in `survey_data$age` are not numerical in the final dataset. Instead, the values are alphanumerical factors. In order to match the values, the column names in `reject_males` and `reject_females` have spaces although it's far from ideal.

**EDIT (2):** Instead of simplified tables as example, the data provided are a small subset of the real dataset. The definition tables `males_reject` and `females_reject` are complete.

**EDIT (3):** The following code finally worked for me. It is the code provided in the answer by r2evans with some small modifications. It splits the initial data in two groups and apply the code to each group separately. Then it is binding rows to compose a new dataset that is written to a csv file. The partial results were kept and written to csv as well for checking purposes.

```
set.seed(42)

## Split the dataset in males and females
survey_data_males <- survey_data %>%
    filter(gender == "Male")

survey_data_females <- survey_data %>%
    filter(gender == "Female")

## Merge with rejection tables
males_result <- males_reject %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -region,
                 names_to = "age",
                 values_to = "drop") %>%
    mutate(age = factor(age)) %>%
    right_join(survey_data_males,
               by = c("region", "age")) %>%
    group_by(region, age) %>%
    filter(is.na(first(drop)) | sample(n()) > first(drop)) %>%
    ungroup()


females_result <- females_reject %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -region,
                 names_to = "age",
                 values_to = "drop") %>%
    mutate(age = factor(age)) %>%
    right_join(survey_data_females,
               by = c("region", "age")) %>%
    group_by(region, age) %>%
    filter(is.na(first(drop)) | sample(n()) > first(drop)) %>%
    ungroup()

completes_to_keep <- bind_rows(males_result,
                               females_result)
write_csv(males_result,
          file = "./out/males_to_keep.csv",
          col_names = TRUE)

write_csv(females_result,
          file = "./out/females_to_keep.csv",
          col_names = TRUE)

write_csv(completes_to_keep,
          file = "./out/completes_to_keep.csv",
          col_names = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steps:

- bring the rownames from `reject_males` as a column, then pivot/reshape so that it is in a long form, more appropriate for joining
- merge it in with `survey_data`
- group by `location` and `age` and remove the number of requisite rows

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
set.seed(42)
reject_males %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column("location") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -location, names_to = "age", values_to = "drop") %>%
  mutate(age = as.integer(age)) %>%
  right_join(survey_data, by = c("location", "age")) %>%
  group_by(location, age) %>%
  filter(is.na(first(drop)) | sample(n()) > first(drop)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 7 × 8
#   location   age  drop    id gender var1  var2  var3 
#   <chr>    <int> <int> <int> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 city_1      18     1     9 male   x9    y9    z9   
# 2 city_1      21     0     2 female x2    y2    z2   
# 3 city_1      21     0     6 female x6    y6    z6   
# 4 city_2      45    NA     4 female x4    y4    z4   
# 5 city_3      46    NA     5 female x5    y5    z5   
# 6 city_3      45    NA     7 male   x7    y7    z7   
# 7 city_1      48    NA     8 female x8    y8    z8
```

Comment: Oops ... meant to add data. It's mostly identical to LMc's sample data, except my `reject_males` has row-names instead of a column of `"location"`, which is how I'm inferring the data is structured based on the sample data in the OP.

Comment: Thanks for that piece of code, I didn't think a join would work here!  I made some modifications to the code like making `age` a factor and removing the `mutate()` function, but I tried and I got not exact number of rejections (some records more than expected in some groups I checked) though. I guess it has something to do with the fact that the examples were **not matching exactly** the data format. I edited the question to add clarity.

Comment: I made some changes to split the initial sample in two groups (males and females) and run the code in both groups separately, binding rows after. I edited the question providind the code that finally worked for me. I can bet it is not the most elegant one, but it worked. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

Here is an option using a helper function and `dplyr::group_modify`. Note this assumes there is a column `location` in your reject data frames. In your post no column name is provided. If that column is row names then you can simply replace `df$location == grp$location` with `grp$location`:

```r
set.seed(1)
library(dplyr)

reject <- list(male = reject_males, female = reject_females) 

remove_sample <- function(dat, grp) {
  df <- reject[[grp$gender]]
  remove_n <- df[df$location == grp$location, as.character(grp$age)]
  if (!is.null(remove_n) && remove_n > 0) {
    return(slice_sample(dat, n = nrow(dat) - remove_n))
  } else {
    return(dat)
  }
}

survey_data |>
  group_by(gender, location, age) |>
  group_modify(remove_sample) |>
  ungroup()
```

I created a small helper function `remove_sample`. This uses the group data information (gender, location, age) to look up the appropriate number you would like to remove.

Using this information it randomly samples the number to *keep* (e.g. # total group rows - # rows you want to remove). If remove values are not available for that gender, location, age combination OR the value is zero then nothing is done.

---

**Data**

```
survey_data <- structure(list(id = 1:9, age = c(18L, 21L, 21L, 45L, 46L, 21L, 
45L, 48L, 18L), gender = c("male", "female", "male", "female", 
"female", "female", "male", "female", "male"), location = c("city_1", 
"city_1", "city_2", "city_2", "city_3", "city_1", "city_3", "city_1", 
"city_1"), var1 = c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6", "x7", 
"x8", "x9"), var2 = c("y1", "y2", "y3", "y4", "y5", "y6", "y7", 
"y8", "y9"), var3 = c("z1", "z2", "z3", "z4", "z5", "z6", "z7", 
"z8", "z9")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

reject_males <- structure(list(location = c("city_1", "city_2", "city_3"), `18` = c(1L, 
0L, 1L), `20` = c(0L, 2L, 5L), `21` = c(0L, 1L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: I can't make it work. I get `Error in slice_sample() 'n' must be a round number, not a <data.frame> object.`
I realised that the age information in the final dataset is not numerical but categorical, therefore I modified the column names in the `reject_males` and `reject_females` objects. But I don't understand the `grp$age`, since there are no 'age' variables in these tables, only in the dataset.
I modified the question above accordingly.

Comment: It would be helpful if you added your data using the `dput` command. For example paste the output of `dput(survey_data)` into your question to preserve column types. Pasting your data as a markdown table is not as helpful.

Comment: You do have an `age` variable in your survey data. What `group_modify` is doing with the helper function is it is splitting your *survey data* into gender, age, location groups. It is iterating over each of those groups and looking up their respective reject numbers, if they have one.

Comment: I edited the question adding real data as suggested using `dput()` expecting it's making things easier. Anyway, I'm trying to understand how the function and the `group_modify()` function work together to make it work.